# Android Studio 3.2.1 menu tools missing item Android

Tags: android-studio-3.2

I have installed Android 3.2.1 from https://developer.android.com/studio/.
I have SDK location in "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" with "SDK Platforms" installed "Android 9.0(Pie)".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU9Ui.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0laTX.png)

I have my JAVA_HOME variable with JDK 1.8.

When I start android studio I don't see under menu Tools many subitems like
"AVD Manager"  "SDK Manager" "Layout Inspector" "Theme Editor" "Connection Assistant" "FireBase" "App link Assistant";

I see the only subitems: "Task & COntexts" "Generate JavaDoc" "Ide Scripting Console" "JShell Console" "Groovy Console" "Kotlin".

My friend has Android Studio 3.2, earlier version and he sees correct subitems under main menu Tools.

I have checked my settings in "Appearance & BEhavior" -> "Menus & Toolbars" -> "Main menu" -> "Tools" and I can see "Android" folder with "AVD Manager"  "SDK Manager" "Layout Inspector" "Theme Editor" ; 
I have also "AndroidToolsGroupExtension" with items " "Connection Assistant" "FireBase" "App link Assistant".

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I've solved, I updated version